# How to position a "add to list" button?

Tags: buttons, lists, floating-action-button

Following picture shows a list of notes in a tab-layout. Each list has a + button at the bottom to create a new note.

[image]

As the list grows the user has to scroll down (a lot) to see, that there is actually a + button. What would be a good way in terms of ux to make the button always visible?

I was thinking of letting the button float over the content. But that could cover the content, which would not be ideal.

Comment: Is this used on desktop, mobile, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your list is in reverse chronological order, it makes sense to put the input (ie what will become the latest entry once you press OK) right at the top.

[image: a text input field above a list]

In this case, the FAB and the dialog box it summons may be entirely unnecessary and/or may be replaced with a "jump to top" link instead.

NB: This pattern only really works if your entries indeed are in reverse chronological order. If they aren't, or you intend for the notes to be unconnected, the connecting lines between the notes don't make sense and neither does having the input box right at the top.

Also, if you worry that the FAB (or a floating input box, for that matter) covers content, make sure you have enough padding for the user to scroll past the content and into empty space a bit, so there always exists at least one position where the FAB doesn't cover the last entry.